# What's the difference between look towards the road and look off towards the road?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

What does 'off' imply here? Would the meaning change if we took it out?

- McVries spoke absently, still looking off towards the road. (from a novel)
- McVries spoke absently, still looking towards the road. (a made up example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"off" here means "away from the focus of attention" or "without any focus".

(To avoid unclear pronouns, I'm going to pretend McVries is a woman)

So the first sentence implies that McVries isn't looking at the person or thing that she normally ought to in her current situation. I imagine she's having a conversation with someone and not meeting their gaze, or there's something she's trying to avoid looking at, like a dead body.

The second sentence suggests McVries was focusing her attention on the road because there's something interesting there.